# How to trigger a click on a dynamically added element

Tags: jquery

This element is dynamically generated. Is it possible to trigger a click on the element?

```
<a unselectable="on" href="javascript:;" onclick="return false;" class="xxx" role="button" aria-haspopup="true">
  <span unselectable="on" class="xxx2">
    New<br>
    Item
    <span unselectable="on" class="xxx3">
      <img unselectable="on" src="xxx">
    </span>
  </span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `trigger('click')` to to achieve this ref http://api.jquery.com/trigger/ ,Hope this helps

```js
$(document).on('click','.xxx',function(e){
   console.log('link has been clicked') 
})

$('.xxx').trigger('click')   // dynamic click event on link
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a unselectable="on" href="javascript:;" onclick="return false;" class="xxx" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"><span unselectable="on" class="xxx2">New<br>Item<span unselectable="on" class="xxx3"><img unselectable="on" src="xxx"></span></span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were trying to ask "*Is it possible to attach a click on the element on dynamic elements?*", then

```
$('body').on('click', function(evt) {
    // Check if its the proper element. Here its anchor tag with class 'xxx'
    if (evt.target.nodeName === 'A' && evt.target.classList.contains('xxx')) {
       // Anchor tag is clicked
    }
}, true);
```

If you have multiple elements which needs to be detected during the event bubbling, this will be useful.